# Conditions on p, f such that $E[H(\tau)] = pH(0) + \int_0^\infty H(t)f(t)dt$ is an expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that a person has to wait a time t before being seated, and that

$$E[H(\tau)] = pH(0) + \int_0^\infty H(t)f(t)dt$$

for all functions $H$ for which this expression is defined.

What are the conditions on $p$ and $f$ for this formula to represent an expectation on $\Omega_t$. Interpret the formula.

My intuition is that this should be interpreted as $p$ is the probability of being seated right away. Then the expectation of $H(\tau)$ would be as indicated, and

$$p + \int_0^\infty f(t)dt = 1$$  I don't know how to put it in mathematical language though, or if there are any other conditions I missed.

Comment: Would you mind to define $H(t)$ and $H(\tau)$, please?

Comment: There really isn't one, other than saying that the expectation above is "for all functions H for which this expression is defined".

Answer (score 1):

Necessary and sufficient conditions are that $p$ is nonnegative, $f$ is nonnegative almost everywhere and measurable, and $p+\displaystyle\int_0^\infty f(t)\mathrm dt=1$.

Then the facts that $p\leqslant1$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty f(t)\mathrm dt\leqslant1$ come as bonuses.

Comment: Thanks! How did you figure this out?

Comment: I looked at the definition of a probability measure.